# How to make body as tall as huge absolutely positioned div in it? I need to have footer at the bottom

Tags: html, css

A have a page with `absolute` positioned drop-down menu. When the menu is visible, it's higher, than the `body`, so it creates some white space below the `footer`, which is positioned at the `bottom` (`bottom:0`) of the `body`.

[image: example]

The expected behavior is that `footer` goes down to the bottom of a scrolled area and visible just after scrolling to the bottom.

How to force the `body` to increase its height when the dropdown is shown or how to make footer be at the bottom? When the tall div is shown, there is a scrollbar in the window, but the `footer` is not at the bottom of the scrolled contents. I don't want to use `position: fixed` since the footer sticks to the bottom of a window and is always visible.

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div style="position:absolute; height:1000px;right:30px;top:30px; border:1px solid red;">
  some long text
  </div>
</div>

something <br>

<div id="footer">
footer
</div>
```

Fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/84k6tvp6/

Comment: I am looking at the answers and wonder why you cannot just set the height of the body and the parent <div> element to 1030px? All the answers seem just to do this by using jQuery!

Comment: Also, if you are going to use javascript, why use JQuery for just this? Why not `document.getElementById("parentDiv").style.height = dcoument.getElementById("childDiv").style.height+50;`   ?

Comment: @jrook as for 1000px - that's just an example of a tall block. Real div has another size, that depends on page and user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with CSS as absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow, and thus their dimensions cannot alter the dimensions of their parents. It can be done by JavaScript by calculating height of the absolute elements and applying it as min-height to the parent.

```js
var minHeight = $(".child").height() + $("#footer").height();
$(".parent").css("min-height", minHeight);
```

```css
#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" style="position:relative">
  <div class="child" style="position:absolute; height:1000px;right:30px;top:30px; border:1px solid red;">
    some tall text
  </div>
</div>

body tag has grey border <br> footer is at the bottom of .. what? <br> absolutely positioned div is taller than body <br>

<div id="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (Dan Philip is right, you need javascript / jQuery)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function setFooter () {
        var h = $("#longDiv").height();
        h += 50; // add to push the footer further
        $("#footer").offset({top: h,left: 0})
        }
    </script>
    <style>
    #footer{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:darkblue;
  color: white;
  font-size:16px;
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:0px;
}
.content{
  position:relative;
  min-height:100%;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="setFooter();">
    <div class="content" style="position:relative">
      <div id="longDiv" style="position:absolute; height:1000px;right:30px;top:30px; border:1px solid red;">
      some tall text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content" style="position:relative">
    body tag has grey border <br>
    footer is at the bottom of .. what? <br>
    absolutely positioned div is taller than body <br>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```